# How to switch out styles in runtime

Tags: android, styles, themes, theming

I want to have a night mode/day mode theme in my app. Currently, I have all screens with day mode.

I have 80+ very complex layout files, 20+ styles defined (7 kinds of text, spinners, etc).

Option 1: Have another set of layouts with _night prefix, referencing _night styles would be a lot of work.

Option 2: switch out colors in runtime..too much work

Is there an easy way to define another theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can set theme in your `Activity` before `setContentView` is called. Something like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(your theme here);
    setContentView(...) 
}
```

If a user changes theme within an `Activity` then you have to restart that `Activity` to see the change.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)

Comment: And how do you define 7 kinds of textview styles, in 2 different themes?